# Fonts not working after using DO Spaces for Django project

Tags: django, fonts, digital-ocean

I've followed this tutorial https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-object-storage-with-django

Everything works except for fonts used in .css files (they are actually loaded by a browser) and some images. Settings are as in tutorial:

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
]
STATIC_URL = 'https://%s/%s/' % (AWS_S3_ENDPOINT_URL, AWS_LOCATION)
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto3.S3Boto3Storage'
```

But when I change the settings back to this, fonts are working:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static/')
```

Note it's not in production. I'm running it on localhost. In DO Spaces CORS configured to allow GET where origin is set to *.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out those font and image files were with private permissions. Changed to public and it works now.